# jQuery Drag/Drop/Sortable-Example: Sorting during moving (= dragging process )

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

The following source code is a working example. I can drag and drop and sort afterwords. But I do not only want to sort afterwords, also during the dragging process. What exactly should I add here?

***JSFIDDLE -> http://jsfiddle.net/w9php/  (All used libraries are attached there)***

**HTML PART**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
       <div class="sequence span3">
            <div id="droppable1" class="droppableBoxes">
                <ol class="choiceMantle cDroppChoiceMantle">
                    <li class="placeholder">Drag here into </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <hr />
        <p class="lead">Drag items below into the box above</p>
        <div class="choices span3">
            <div id="qID_2" class="choiceMantle unsortedChoiceBox1">
                <ol>    
                    <li id="item-16" class="draggable1">Cappuccino</li>
                    <li id="item-19" class="draggable1">Latte</li>
                    <li id="item-33" class="draggable1">Espresso</li>
                    <li id="item-33" class="draggable1">Melange</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

**jQuery PART**

```
var i1 = 0;

$( "#droppable1 ol" ).droppable({
        scope: "d1",
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: '.unsortedChoiceBox1 li',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            i1++;
            ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',false); 
            $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
            ui.draggable.clone().appendTo(this);
            ui.draggable.remove();
        }
}).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
        }
});


$('.unsortedChoiceBox1 li').draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: true,
        scope: "d1",
        cursor: 'move',
});
```

***JSFIDDLE -> http://jsfiddle.net/w9php/  (All used libraries are attached there)***

p.s. JsFiddle can not really handle Bootstrap, it should look some differently but the look in this example is not crucial...

Comment: You need to lists which are sortable, but only one should accept items from the other - is my understanding correct..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the option is [connectToSortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-connectToSortable) of the draggable

But that is not working because of you using droppable and sortable both. I dont understand the purpose, but if u initialize it as a sortable and use connectToSortable option in the draggable, u wont need the droppable